# "Запомнить меня" при авторизации пользователя

Tags: авторизация, cookie, php

Добрый день.

Нужно к системе авторизации пользователей добавить возможность запоминания пользователя, если он установился галочку "запомнить меня" при авторизации. Авторизация у меня происходит через сессию. Т.е. проверили данные о юзере с данными из БД и записали данные в сессию.

Как реализовывал "запомнить меня" - если юзер нажал галочку, то когда пишу данные в сессию об авторизации пишу и кукисы -

```
setcookie('login', $foo1 ,time()+604800, "/");setcookie('pass', $foo2 ,time()+604800, "/");
```

При разлогинивании убиваю сессию и удаляю кукисы -

```
setcookie ("login", "", time()-14800); setcookie ("pass", "", time()-14800);session_destroy();
```

Но проблема в том, что при разлогинивании сессия удаляется, а вот кукисы нет, не знаю почему.

Далее, на странице авторизации, куда у меня идёт редирект, после разлогинивания вызывается метод, этот метод делает проверку на наличии кукисов и если они есть, то проверяем данные из куков и авторизуем юзера. Но из-за того, что кукисы не удалились при разлогинивании у меня происходит снова запуск сесссии и залогинивание юзера, таким образом я вообще не могу разлогиниться. Думал дело в браузере, но перепробовал и в хроме и в Екплоуер и в Мазиле. Сам не могу разобраться в чём причина, уже 2 дня. Очень нужна помощь.

```
static  function saveMe(){
    // проверяем наличие куки в браузере пользователя
    if(isset($_COOKIE['login'])){
        if(!empty($_COOKIE['login']) && empty($_SESSION['mail'])){
            // кука найдена, теперь сверим данные пользователя с данными в БД сайта
            $db = new db('yes');
            $findUser = $db->isset_user($_COOKIE['login'],$_COOKIE['pass']);
            if(!empty($findUser['id'])){
                $_SESSION['okauth'] = true;
                $_SESSION['mail'] = $findUser['mail_user'];
                $_SESSION['privileged'] = $findUser['privileged'];
            }
            unset($db);
        }
    } }
```

Comment: @juniorspecialistphp, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: @juniorspecialistphp для того чтобы отблагодарить автора, нажмите на «Палец вверх» и кнопку «Принять ответ».

Answer (score 5):

```
setcookie("login", "", time()+604800, "/");
setcookie("pass", "", time()+604800, "/");
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Спасибо, как же всё просто оказалось :-)